# addLiquidity() function fails on UniswapV2 on local ganache instance?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, uniswap

addLiquidity() function reverts without any reason on local development instance of ganache, any ideas why this might be happening?

Some background:

- I have forked the UniswapV2Factory and UniswapV2Router02 and deployed on ganache.
- I have created 2 ERC20 tokens, and created a pair (via factory.createPair()) for them.
- Minted both ERC20 tokens to my address.
- I have approved token amounts to the router contract address (via erc20.approve() function)

This is how I am calling the addLiquidity Function

```js
const blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
const timestamp = block.timestamp + 300;

await router.addLiquidity(
    ERC20_TOKEN_1_ADDRESS,
    ERC20_TOKEN_2_ADDRESS,
    web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'),
    web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'),
    web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether'),
    web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether'),
    OWNER_ADDRESS,
    timestamp,
    { gas: 4000000 }
)
```

Comment: i had the same error when forked uniswap. in my case, the problem was in the `UniswapV2Library` at `pairFor` method. they use some fancy tricks here, and for some reasons in fact it returned not correct address for deployed pair in fork (copy-past the contracts to another repo, maybe it was a compiler issue). with wrong address, it failed on `getReserves` call. what i did was copying not contracts, but `.json` files from `build` directory and use these files in tests and deployment. suddenly, it worked.. hope it helps you

Comment: @invisiblecat I was actually able to fix this. The function `pairFor` uses the creation code hash of the UniswapV2Pair contract. Since I had deployed it on my own private network, I needed to update the hash in the library, before deploying the library.

Comment: from where did you get the new code hash?

Comment: @invisiblecat you can either hash the source code of `UniswapV2Pair` contract or use the `factory.pairCodeHash()` function which does the same.

Comment: wow thank you! i didn't know that..
funny that you was one asked a question but at the end me, attempted answerer, getting new knowlegde dx